# :erlang.bit_size(nil) error when first argument in function is zero

Tags: erlang, elixir

```
defmodule Complex do
    def complex_to_string(r, i) do
        to_str = ""
        to_str = to_str <>
        if r != 0 do
            "#{r}"
        end

        to_str = to_str <>
        cond do
            i < 0 or (r == 0 and i != 0) ->
                "#{i}i"
            i > 0 ->
                "+#{i}i"
            :true ->
                ""
        end
        to_str
    end
end
```

Everything works fine when first argument is not zero.

```
iex(111)> Complex.complex_to_string(-1, 4)
"-1+4i"
iex(109)> Complex.complex_to_string(4, 2)
"4+2i"
iex(110)> Complex.complex_to_string(4, 0)
"4"
```

After calling function with zero as a first parameters error happens.

`iex(111)> Complex.complex_to_string(0, 4)`

> ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>       :erlang.bit_size(nil)
>       iex:111: Complex.complex_to_string/2

Why is this happening? Is it possible to call a function with first parameter as zero? If not then why?

### Edit 1:

After quick analysis I've managed to deal with this problem. The problem was that `if r == 0` then `to_str <> nil` would happen. **There was no default option (else) for conditional instruction**.

```
    to_str = to_str <>
    cond do 
        r != 0 -> 
            "#{r}"
        true ->
            ""
    end
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `cond` with two conditions considered to be an anti-pattern by core team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While with the @Dogbert’s answer it works, the whole code is very counter-idiomatic. In Elixir, we mostly use patter-matching instead of spaghetti `if`s. It’s always better to handle corner cases explicitly:

```rb
defmodule Complex do
  def complex_to_string(r, i)
    when not is_number(r) or not is_number(i),
    do: raise "Unexpected input"

  # added for clarity, (r, 0) covers the case
  def complex_to_string(0, 0), do: "0"

  def complex_to_string(r, 0), do: "#{r}"
  def complex_to_string(0, i), do: "#{i}i"
  def complex_to_string(r, i)
    when i > 0, do: "#{r}+#{i}i"
  # guard below is redundant, added for clarity
  def complex_to_string(r, i)
    when i < 0, do: "#{r}#{i}i"
end

[{-1,5},{2,0},{0,-2},{0,0},{-3,-3}]
|> Enum.map(fn {r, i} ->
     Complex.complex_to_string(r, i)
   end)
#⇒ ["-1+5i", "2", "-2i", "0", "-3-3i"]
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line:

```
to_str = to_str <>
  if r != 0 do
    "#{r}"
  end
```

When `r == 0`, the `if` returns `nil` (because there is no `else` block) which can't be appended to a String. If you don't want to append anything if `r == 0`, return `""` from `else`:

```
to_str = to_str <>
  if r != 0 do
    "#{r}"
  else
    ""
  end
```

or shorter:

```
to_str = to_str <> if(r != 0, do: "#{r}", else: "")
```